# Load Sectors to RAM in qemu

Tags: assembly, qemu, bootloader, sector

---

I code a simple program which loads the sector (sector num.2) to the RAM

but prints nothing.

first, I tried this code for bootsector:

```
org 0x7c00

mov ax, 0x1000 ; ES:BX = 1000:0000
mov es, ax
mov bx, 0x00

LoadSectortoMemory:
mov al, 0x01 ; Load 1 sectors
mov ah, 0x02 ; Load disk data to ES:BX
mov cl, 0x02 ; Sector = 2
mov ch, 0x00 ; Cylinder = 0
mov dl, 0x00 ; Drive = 0
mov dh, 0x00 ; Head = 0
int 13h ; Read
jc LoadSectortoMemory ; ERROR => Try again

jmp 0x1000:0x0000

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

the kernel which takes the username and password from user then terminate the program:

```
mov si,Username

call Write
call Read
call Next_Line
call Pass
call Read
call Next_Line
call Kernel_Exit

Write:
mov al,[si]
mov ah,0x0e
mov bl,0x07
mov bh,0x00
int 0x10
inc si
mov dl,[si]
cmp dl,0x00
jne Write
ret

Read:
mov ah,0x00
int 0x16
mov ah,0x0e
mov bl,0x07
mov bh,0x00
int 0x10
cmp al,0x0d
jne Read
ret

Pass:
mov si,Password
call Write
ret

Next_Line:
mov al,0x0a
mov ah,0x0e
mov bl,0x07
mov bh,0x00
int 0x10
ret

Kernel_Exit:
mov si,Done
call Write
mov ah,0x4c
int 0x21

Username db 'Username: ',0
Password db 'Password: ',0
Done db 'Done',0

times 510-($-$$) db 0
```

and didn't work

after searching I tried this code (just registers added at the end:/):

```
bits 16
org 0x7c00

mov ax, 0x1000 ; ES:BX = 1000:0000
mov es, ax
mov bx, 0x00

LoadSectortoMemory:
mov al, 0x01 ; Load 1 sectors
mov ah, 0x02 ; Load disk data to ES:BX
mov cl, 0x02 ; Sector = 2
mov ch, 0x00 ; Cylinder = 0
mov dl, 0x00 ; Drive = 0
mov dh, 0x00 ; Head = 0
int 0x13 ; Read!
jc LoadSectortoMemory ; ERROR => Try again

mov ax, 0x1000
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax
mov fs, ax
mov gs, ax
mov ss, ax

jmp 0x1000:0x0

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

again didn't work

command lines which I use:

`nasm -fbin BootSector.asm -o Bootsector.bin`

`nasm -fbin Kernel.asm -o Kernel.bin`

`cat BootSector.bin Kernel.bin > Code.bin`

`qemu-system-x86_64 Code.bin`

is it a problem with qemu?

can anyone help me with my problem?

thanks in advance

Comment: Works for me if you specify `qemu-system-i386 -fda code.bin`, not sure why.

Comment: Oh of course. You're setting `mov dl, 0` which forces the drive to zero. Remove that line to use the ROM-BIOS unit as initialised by the loader, and it will work without `-fda`.

Comment: @ecm thank you so so much, mate. helped me a lot. just a question: without adding ax to fs and gs and the other registers (the 2nd boot sector which I tried ) it prints something unusual. why does this happen?

Comment: Refer to the second point in my answer. Setting `fs`, `gs`, and `es` is not needed. Setting `ds` is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code. First, the most important one:

```
LoadSectortoMemory:
mov al, 0x01 ; Load 1 sectors
mov ah, 0x02 ; Load disk data to ES:BX
mov cl, 0x02 ; Sector = 2
mov ch, 0x00 ; Cylinder = 0
mov dl, 0x00 ; Drive = 0
mov dh, 0x00 ; Head = 0
int 0x13 ; Read!
jc LoadSectortoMemory ; ERROR => Try again
```

This only works if you're being booted from drive unit zero. By default, qemu appears to set up your image as drive unit 80h (hda = first harddisk). You're assuming that you are loaded from unit 0 (fda = first diskette). Therefore, you need to either use the parameters `-fda code.bin` to tell qemu to use your file as a diskette image, and/or drop the line modifying `dl` to use the unit-to-load-from as initialised by the ROM-BIOS before it transfers control to your loader.

---

You already modified your loader to set the segment registers. Especially `ds` needs to be set to 1000h because your kernel uses that segment register (implicitly) to access its messages. (Your kernel.asm has no `org` line so NASM uses its default of `org 0` here.) Instead of setting `ds` in the boot loader, you could also add the following to the start of kernel.asm:

```
push cs
pop ds
```

This sets `ds` to the value of `cs`. In Real 86 Mode, this is valid to get a data segment reference with the same base address as the code segment (but with Read/Write permissions).

---

Besides setting `ss` you should also set `sp`. You should set `sp` in the immediately following instruction to the one that sets `ss`. Example:

```
mov ax, 1000h
cli
mov ss, ax
xor sp, sp
sti
```

This sets up `sp` to equal zero. Because of underflow, the first used stack slot will be at `ss:0FFFEh` (the top of the full 64 KiB segment).

---

In `Kernel_Exit` you're using interrupt 21h service 4Ch. This service is not available to you in this environment. You should use something else, such as this:

```
xor ax, ax
int 16h ; wait for key pressed
int 19h ; reboot
```

Or this:

```
sti
halt:
hlt ; wait for external interrupt, keep CPU usage low
jmp halt ; jump infinitely to stop program flow
```

---

In `Next_Line` you have this:

```
Next_Line:
mov al,0x0a
mov ah,0x0e
mov bl,0x07
mov bh,0x00
int 0x10
ret
```

This only happens to work because each time you use `Next_Line` you previously used `Read` which ends when it displayed a terminating 13 (CR = Carriage Return). `Next_Line`, to be more general, should display first a 13 (CR) and then a 10 (LF = Line Feed). That is, you should do this:

```
Next_Line:
mov al, 13
mov ah,0x0e
mov bl,0x07
mov bh,0x00
int 0x10
mov al, 10
int 10h
ret
```

---

You're using the line `times 510-($-$$) db 0` at the end of kernel.asm. You should use `times 512 - ($ - $$) db 0` instead, to fill the entire sector, not just up to 510 bytes.